# Capistrano continues with next tasks after assets:precompile for webpack fails when running locally

Tags: capistrano, webpacker

After *assets: precompile* fails when compiling the webpacker pack locally, Capistrano continues with the next steps of the deployment. Resulting in the application being deployed with the Javascript files missing.

Is there something special that has to be done in the locally run tasks so Capistrano exits without running the following tasks? Or is it a problem from webpacker that is not raising an exception?

I'm precompiling the assets locally with this task:

```
run_locally do
  execute "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake 'assets:clean'"
  execute "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake 'assets: precompile'"
end
```